# Difference between `where` in the query object and `if` in the extension methods

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, deferred-execution

I am studying `LINQ`.

I don't know the difference between using `if` in extension method and using `where` in query object.

The `Console.WriteLine()` results are the same, is there any difference in speed?

If you think about it, there seems to be a difference in readability, but that's my guess.

To be honest, I know it's a useless curious, but I was so curious about it, so I wrote it.

We look forward to hearing from you.

**Oh, if there is anything in the article that needs to be improved, please advise.**

```cs
...

public static IEnumerable<Student> GetTeenAgerStudents(this IEnumerable<Student> source)
{
  foreach (Student std in source)
  {
    yield return std;
  }
}

...

var teenAgerStudents = from s in studentList.GetTeenAgerStudents()
                       where s.Age >= 10 && s.Age < 20
                       select s;
```

```cs
...

public static IEnumerable<Student> GetTeenAgerStudents(this IEnumerable<Student> source)
{
  foreach (Student std in source)
  {
    if (std.Age >= 10 && std.Age < 20)
          yield return std;
  }
}

...

var teenAgerStudents = from s in studentList.GetTeenAgerStudents()
                       select s;
```

The above code is referenced from https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-deferred-execution.

Comment: *is there any difference in speed*. One way to answer that: [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  prediction the exact speed difference between them. `if` is faster. But for legibility reasons, where is the most commonly used route. You can understand `where` like a `sql` query. Here, it filters some data from the data collection and reveals the ones that are suitable for you. Looks like `T-Sql`.